# Calling ajax from struts2 to populate a div 

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, struts2

I have a drop down and have a JavaScript function tied to the onchange event of the drop down.I need to call a action class with the drop down selected value and fetch data from database.I need pointers to call the action class from JavaScript and also pass the selected value of drop down to fire a DB select query and update a table present in a div withou refreshing the whole page.

My drop down

```
<s:select name="newQuestion.CertificationId" list="certificationList"
    listKey="certificationId" listValue="certificationName" headerKey=""
    headerValue="Select Certification" label="Certification Name"
    onchange="getQuestionsList(this.value)" />
```

Javascript function

```
function getQuestionsList(val) {
        alert("Here" + val);



    }
```

Basically for each of the drop down selected values I need a ajax call to DB to populate a div which is hidden currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is it you need assistance with? From what I understand, you have it all figured out (minus the ajax call to the Struts action).

All you need to make it work is:

- What URL you need to call the Struts
  action
- How to make the call to the Struts
  action
- How to change the contents of a
  div element using Javascript

Some helpful Google hits: [Struts and Ajax Working Together](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/21-ajax-support-in-struts-20-2.html), [Changing content on the fly using Javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/dcontent.aspx).

You have the right direction, now go and make the final touches.

Comment: I need to pass the certification Id from the drop down and pass it to the action class to generate the data for that particular id.

Comment: I need to understand how can i retrieve the certification id available to me in the action class of struts2

Comment: @Sam You can pass the id from the drop down to the server as a normal querystring parameter. If your action URL is for example http://myhost.com/MyAction.do, then you can just append the id to that URL when making the Ajax call, like this: http://myhost.com/MyAction.do?registrationId=123. You can access that parameter in your Struts action, something like `getRequest().getParameter("registrationId")`

Comment: The getRequest() method which you are referring belong to which class.I tried fetching the request paramter using the below mentioned code but found some garbage ** Map srt= ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();** 
  System.out.println("H vlues os"+srt.get("id").toString());

Comment: @Sam In Struts2 you should use the ParameterAware interface to get to the querystring parameters. There's a nice example of it here: http://strutstwo.blogspot.com/2007/06/accessing-request-parameters-in-your.html. Also check out other useful info about it, search Google for "struts2 parameteraware".

Comment: I have a list generated in Action class which I am modifying at the change of another drop down and am coming back to the same jsp but the changed values is not getting reflected

Comment: @Sam Based on that information, it's hard to say what the problem is. My guess is that you probably are not passing the changed list back to the JSP view. Have you already tried to run your code in debug mode? Set a breakpoint at the action's beginning and see what it actually does. It might be that you're change is not implemented correctly.

Comment: <div id="questionDetails" class="registrationDetails"
 style="display: none;"><span> <b> Question List</b> </span> <br>
<br>I have this div which is initially hidden which I am unhiding in my JS function.Although I change the list which this iterator is reflecting in action class the changed value is not reflected
<table class="registrationDetailsTable">
 <tr class="tabledataheader">
  

 <s:iterator value="questionList">
  <tr class="tabledatarow">
   <td><s:property value="questionId" /></td>
   <td><s:property value="questionDesc" /></td>
 </s:iterator>
 </tr>

Comment: The problem is am not reloading the page but only unhiding the div and hence the new values of action class is not reflected here.Any ideas to solve this issue would be great.'

Comment: @Sam If you have the code that updates the list, but you do not call it anywhere, then of course the list won't be updated on the page. That's just like assuming that the TV channel will change because the "change channel" button exists on the remote controller. You either must reload the page to reflect the new situation or call the action using an Ajax query, just like you've outlined in your original question.

Comment: The problem is I am submitting to a action where I am modifying the list to be displayed .but when in struts.xml I am redirecting to this jsp It is taking it as a fresh request and getting null values which is by default when you dont have any value selected in the drop down.

Comment: @Sam When you call your action, it must change the list and make the updated list available to the JSP (for example by relaying it as a request attribute). Then the action should forward to the JSP view, which builds the list based on what's in the request. Have you checked out any tutorials on how you can display the action's data on the view? For example, are you able to follow and understand this tutorial: http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/dispatchAction-in-struts-2-example-1.html You should study the web resources more if simple parameter passing leaves you confused.

Comment: Its not about parameter passing

Comment: Hi  deltaforce2,I have created a new question for my issue citing all needed code.Can you please look into that